# Add instance of class in vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am trying to make a static vector of a class (called "radsurf") so when a instance is constructed it will be appended to the vector.

But I have had some issues when compiling the code using g++.

It tells me there is "no matching function for call" for the static vector of the class.

Can someone help me?

Tree View:

```
├── include
│   └── radsurf.h
└── radiacaoapp.cpp
```

radiacaoapp.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "include/radsurf.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    radsurf a(0.1); // creates one instance
    radsurf b(0.5); // creates another instance

    // read the list of "e" parameters of the radsurf instances
    for (radsurf x : radsurf::L) {
        cout << x.e << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

radsurf.h:

```
#ifndef RADSURF_H
#define RADSURF_H
#include <vector>

    class radsurf{
        public:
            // "e" parameter - each instance has its own
            float e; 
            // L vector that contains all instances of radsurf classes
            static std::vector<radsurf> L; 
            radsurf(float e){
                // assign constructor argument to the "e" parameter of the instance
                this->e=e;
                // adds the instance to the list
                L.push_back(this);
            }
    };

#endif // RADSURF_H
```

Error of g++ compiler:

```
[chandler@chandler-PC radiacaoapptest]$ g++ radiacaoapp.cpp -o test.bin
In file included from radiacaoapp.cpp:3:
include/radsurf.h: In constructor ‘radsurf::radsurf(float)’:
include/radsurf.h:15:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<radsurf>::push_back(radsurf*)’
   15 |                 L.push_back(this);
      |                                 ^
```

Comment: Your vector doesn't store pointers, so you can't push a pointer into it. You could push `*this` but that makes a copy. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I need to recall all the "e" parameters (to do some calculations) of all instances created in the execution later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, the `this` keyword is a **pointer** to the current object instance. Your `std::vector<radsurf>` is a vector of `radsurf` objects, not pointers to `radsurf` objects (not `radsurf*`s).

The static vector should instead by a `std::vector<radsurf*>`, meaning it contains a list of radsurf pointers. If you instead want a vector of values (which I doubt), then you can instead `L.push_back(*this);` to dereference `this` before copying it in.